# Creating Verified Email in Google Scholar for Non Academic (no institutional affiliation)

Tags: email, google-scholar, publications

How can I create a verified email address (which requires an institutional affiliation) in google scholar when I was in private practice?  I have no institutional affiliation.  This matters because my profile and presumably my publications cannot appear in search results without the verified email.

Comment: Do you have any other email ID that is not from GMail, Yahoo, etc.? For example, from a personal domain or a domain for your business?